# Strange timstamp value in scroll event object. Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was working with scroll events and find out quite strange timestamp value in a scroll event object.

```
timeStamp: 552166.3550000011
```

It doesn't look like a classic timestamp value like `1519211809934` for a example.
There is no information about new timestamp format on https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp

Date/time is correct. `Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

What it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its timeStamp starts from page-load in milliseconds. Protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp

Docs: The timeStamp read-only property of the Event interface returns the time (in milliseconds) at which the event was created.

To offer protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting, the precision of Event.timeStamp might get rounded depending on browser settings.

So for example, if you wait for 10 seconds and then scroll - event.timeStamp would be like this

`10280.069999978878`